# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type dependency injection .net core web api

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-7.0

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Pwc.EMSWebapi.IUserManagementService' while attempting to activate 'Pwc.EMSWebapi.UserManagementController'.
 `at lambda_method3(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[]) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)`

I added below in program.cs file:-

```
` services.AddTransient<IUserManagementRepoitory, UserManagementRepoitory>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();`
I tried below in program.cs file:-
` services.AddTransient<IUserManagementRepoitory, UserManagementRepoitory>();
    services.AddTransient<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();`
```

```
 `services.AddScoped<IUserManagementService, UserManagementService>();`
```

Edit:-

my controller

```
public 

    UserManagementController(IUserManagementService userManagementService)
            {
                this._userManagementService = userManagementService;
                //this.applicationUser = applicationUser;
            //this.user = user;
        }
```

service:-

public

```
UserManagementService(IUserManagementRepository userManagementRepoitory)
        {
            this._userManagementRepoitory = userManagementRepoitory;
        }
```

Repository

```
 public UserManagementRepoitory(EMSDbContext bcDbContext, IUser user)
        {
            this.dbContext = bcDbContext;
            this.user = user;
        }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this part of the code you provided, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The most likely cause of this error is because there exists a second type in the application that is named `IUserManagementService`. Check if the type referenced by the controller is the same type as registered in the program.cs. If you are using Visual Studio as your IDE, you can set the cursor on the type name and press `F12`. This will jump to the implementation.

Comment: btw, the code samples are really badly formatted. You should consider posting better formatted code examples the next time you raise a question. If you want others to spend their spare time on answering your questions, you should invest in making it as easy as possible for them to answer your question.